# how to search a file only in user profile and root in linux/unix

Tags: linux, find, sh

Currently i am using the below find command to find the cert8.db file

> find / -type f -path '*.mozilla*/*' -name "cert8.db"

The above command is trying to search the file everywhere.

I would like to scan the file only under root and user profiles(Unknown, unknown1 etc).

most common location for this file is:

> in root: /root/.mozilla/firefox/i636e2gs.default/cert8.db
>
> profile unknown:
>   /home/unknown/.mozilla/firefox/bz5xry7t.default-beta/cert9.db
>
> profile unknown1:
>   /home/unknown1/.mozilla/firefox/bz5xry7t.default-beta/cert9.db

Note: I am not sure, this could be the Mozilla's default initialization location.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` expects zero, one, or more paths where to look for files and apply its expressions. Replace (`/` = file system root) with all locations you want to be searched:

```
find /root /home -type f -path '.mozilla/*' -name 'cert8.db'
```

You might even limit the search space further by moving the `.mozilla` part into the list of starting points if it is a reasonable assumption that the `.mozilla` directory is always a direct child of the root folder or the home directories (making your shell do the work instead of find):

```
find /root/.mozilla/firefox /home/*/.mozilla/firefox -type f -name 'cert8.db'
```

Comment: Thanks @knittl, I have a doubt here, this command runs over 1000(Linux 7/centos 7) machines, is there a chance where .mozila's installation path would be different. I am very new to Linux env, sorry for the basic question

Comment: @unknown usually not, but anything is possible (reconfigured software, custom compiled software, …). In that case use only `/root /home` as starting points